# How to optimize code so that Python script does not use up all memory and swap space?

Tags: python, memory

I'm trying to update a database using 2 files, one containing the data and another containing the rules for how the data should be updated, but my computer kept hanging upon reaching a certain line in the data file. After checking with System Monitor, I realized that this was because my script was using up all the memory and swap space.

This is how my code looks like:

```
def update_db():
    with open(DATA_FILEPATH, 'r') as DATA, open(RULES_FILEPATH, 'r') as RULES: # DATA file is ~10mb, RULES file is ~115kb

    for line in DATA:
        # processing

        # go to the beginning of the RULES file
        RULES.seek(0)
        # for each line, check which rule applies
            for rule_line in RULES:
                # more processing
```

When I run my script with very truncated versions of the 2 files (2-3 lines each), there are no issues. Is there a way to optimize my code so that it doesn't use up so much memory?

Comment: It's hard to imagine that the code that you posted, working with relatively small files, would exhaust all memory. What processing is going on?

Comment: It's mostly very simple parsing (splitting by tabs, stripping unwanted characters etc). If a DATA line satisfies a particular rule, I update it in my database using previously written functions.

Comment: Just a minor thing: `with open(RULES_FILEPATH, 'r') as RULES:` should be directly after you open the `DATA` file, so that you don't open it for every line again and again. After going through the lines of the `RULES` file, you just call `RULES.seek(0)` to go to the beginning of the file again.

Comment: you are opening `RULES_FILEPATH` the number of times you have lines in `DATA_FILEPATH`. So for 10byte data lines you open that file 1 million times. No wonder it is swamping your os.

Comment: Still getting low on memory and swap space if I open the file just once and use seek(0) to return to the beginning as Tim Zimmerman suggested.

Comment: don't mess with your file handles like this. just read the rules in mem and close the rulesfile.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a better structure:

```
def update_db():
    rules = []
    with open(RULES_FILEPATH, 'r') as ifile: # RULES file is ~115kb
        for line in ifile:
            rules.append(line)

    with open(DATA_FILEPATH, 'r') as ifile: # DATA file is ~10mb
        for line in ifile:
            # processing

            # for each line, check which rule applies
            for rule_line in rules:
                # more processing
```

Comment: then it is in `processing` or `more processing`. Did you [profile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) your code?